# How to write a regexp for email which will find the starting and with space whether any email is there are not?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with a problem. I'm trying to find the emails from the string. I need a regexp which will find the email in starting and in middle with space. like it should detect the `test@domain.com` and 
`<space>test@domain.com`. here in middle of the string the email should start with space. I'm trying with below regexp, but it is not working.

`([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)`

Comment: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the following regular expression.It's greedy in nature

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+?@[a-zA-Z0-9+-]+?\.com
```

Comment: my answer is tailored towards op's test case that he provided

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty fool proof..

```
(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))
```

see the test here... https://regex101.com/r/M8WmoV/1

```js
var stringThing = `wadadaaaaaa@gmail.net.com everyone, I stuck with a problem. I'm trying to find the emails from the shibbydibby@flibbyfloopy.net string. I need a regexp which will find the email in starting and in middle with space. like it should detect the test@domain.com and <space>test@domain.com.net. here in middle of the string the email should start with space. I'm trying with below regexp it is shibbydibby.net not working. `;

var emails = extractEmailsFromString(stringThing)
console.log(emails);

function extractEmailsFromString(str){
    return str.match(/(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))/g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go with `([-.+\w ]+)@([-\w]+)\.(\w+)`, you can get the username & the domain in the result.